# Including log4net into a .net web application built with .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, log4net

I saw that there's many, many thread about this on the web, also in stackoverflow, but i didn't find any way to resolve my problem. I've tried 3 things about now and it all didn't works :

1. I've simply tried to get the log4net.dll whos given from the log4net zip folder with all source code in the bin directory. **Results** : No compilation error, but my SmtpAppender just don't send errors email.
2. So, I've search from web to find that it *can* be related to the version that the log4net.dll were compile. Which is wierd but anyway, I ran into one error whos asking me to generate a strong key for the assembly and that's what I've done and compile so I release this project and take the log4net.dll and add it to my projet's refereces. **Result** : No compilation error but 1 error when it is trying to configure from the Global.asax line :

   ```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
   }
   ```

   Here's the error : (See #Ref1)
3. So, again, I've found out this thread from a certain Ahmed Fouad whos, according to me, were looking to works fine. [Here's the thread](http://fouad.laplacesoftware.com/). I've done everything he says but I still run into the same error (#Ref1).

Do anyone succeeded to configure SmtpAppender into a C# VS.net Web Appplication using Framework 4.0 ?

#### Ref1

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden

---

### Additional informations (Review #1)

I've just tried something else. I've open the complete .sln of the log4net application converted with VS.net 2010, added a web project looking exactly the same as my application but in this case, I'm able to debug Log4net library. Here's where it fails :

```
// If we could not find an alias
if (rep == null)
{
    LogLog.Debug("DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository [" + repositoryName + "] using type [" + repositoryType + "]");

    // Call the no arg constructor for the repositoryType
    HERE -> rep = (ILoggerRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType); <-- HERE

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Note that I've not forget to put EVERYTHING I were putting before into my web.config.Debug (and/or release). But, can it miss things? Web.Config are a lot different if we comprare with .net 3.*

Comment: does logging work if you use something simpler like a file appender?

Comment: Yup, file appender raise the same error. But see my main post, i've just had some informations.

Comment: Version 1.2.11 supports .Net 4... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-233

Comment: Thanks Stephan. You are right, Log4net now support on .Net4. But at the very moment I've posted it, it was not. Thanks to specify though! (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find it!! I've read this post [Log4Net and .NET 4.0 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279896/log4net-and-net-4-0-rc) and it simply just solve it!

In my first post (the question), at step 3 of things i've tried, it says to replace something in AssemblyInfo.cs :

He says : "In AssemblyInfo.cs, modified the part for Partial Security to be like this:"

```
  (#)if (!NETCF && !NET_4_0)
  //
  // If log4net is strongly named it still allows partially trusted callers
  //
  [assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
  (#)endif
```

It's not good!! You must remove the "!NET_4_0" and replace the [assembly] by this line :

```
  [assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

Both SMTPAppender and FileAppender now working fine for me!

Comment: Hey Will! "ol'friend", not so much, I'm still young you know ;o)

Answer (score 4):

You'll still get this error message using log4net v1.2.11 under a partial trust 4.0 website eg:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Medium" />
```

If there is no necessity for partial trust, changing this to:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
```

stops the error.