# AutoMapper / Castle - Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member

Tags: .net-4.0, castle-windsor, automapper, s#arp-architecture

I am getting the following exception when calling any of my Mapper.Map methods.

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Castle.Core.Logging.LevelFilteredLogger.InitializeLifetimeService()'.
>   Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method being overriden.

I am using the latest build of AutoMapper downloaded from codeplex inside my S#arp 1.6 application running on .Net 4.0 (which is using version 1.2.0.6623 of Castle.Core).

I beleive it has something to do with the new .Net 4.0 security settings which I don't quite understand.

Is there a way to fix it?

Paul

Comment: Have you tried both the merged and unmerged AutoMapper assembly? I got this problem with the merged one - changing to unmerged fixed it (Automapper v2.0.0.200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something from a little googling which fixed my problem, i'm not sure if this is the ideal or recommended approach but it worked.

I added this to the Automapper projects 'AssemblyInfo.cs' file:

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

I recompiled and used the new DLL and everything worked fine.

Please leave comments if this isn't reccomended or if there is a better approach.

For now though i will leave my own answer as the correct one.

Thanks for the help though!

**UPDATE:**

My mappings are pretty simple, sorry about all the code but thought it may help you:

Initialisation Code:

```
Mapper.Reset();
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddProfile<LeadsProfile>();
    //x.AddProfile<AttendeeProfile>();
});

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

LeadsProfile.cs

```
public class LeadsProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
        {
            public override string ProfileName
            {
                get { return "LeadsProfile"; }
            }

            protected override void Configure()
            {

                Mapper.CreateMap<Lead, LeadDto>();

                Mapper.CreateMap<Lead, LeadDetailDto>();

                Lead lead = null;
                Mapper.CreateMap<int, LeadDetailDto>()
                    .BeforeMap((s, d) => lead = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILeadRepository>().FindOne(s))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Id, x => x.MapFrom(s => lead.Id))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Fullname, x => x.MapFrom(s => lead.Fullname))
                    .ForMember(d => d.TelNumber, x => x.MapFrom(s => lead.TelNumber))
                    .ForMember(d => d.BookedAppointmentDate, x => x.MapFrom(s => lead.BookedAppointmentDate));

            }

        }
```

Source Class

```
public class Lead : Entity
    {
        public Lead()
        {
            Status = Common.LeadStatus.Raw;
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public Lead(Branch branch, Promoter promoter, LeadSource source, string fullname, string telNumber, Address address, DateTime apptDate) : this()
        {
            this.Branch = branch;
            this.Promoter = promoter;
            this.Source = source;
            this.Fullname = fullname;
            this.TelNumber = telNumber;
            this.Address = address;
            this.BookedAppointmentDate = apptDate;
        }

        public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
        public virtual Promoter Promoter { get; set; }
        public virtual LeadSource Source { get; set; }
        public virtual Common.LeadStatus Status { get; set; }

        public virtual bool ExistingCustomer { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsDoso { get; set; }

        public virtual string TitlePrefix { get; set; }
        public virtual string Fullname { get; set; }
        public virtual string TelNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime BookedAppointmentDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<LeadProduct> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Sale> Sales { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Destination Dto's

```
public class LeadDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string TelNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookedAppointmentDate { get; set; }
    }

public class LeadDetailDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string TelNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookedAppointmentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share an example of the source/destination mappings?  If this is a bug, I'd love to get a regression test in.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my code, hope it helps...be great if this could be fixed so I don't have to recompile the project.

Comment: Added this attribute to the source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try upgrading Castle.Core to 2.5, which has been built and tested specifically against .net 4.0. (I should note that Castle.Core 2.5 is also available for .net 3.5 and SL 3/4)

Related questions:

- [Log4Net and .NET 4.0 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279896/log4net-and-net-4-0-rc)
- [Weird override problem with Fluent NHibernate and .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924814/weird-override-problem-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-net-4)